# Migrate content from SP Online with classic sites to SP online with Modern experience

Tags: migration

Does anyone knows if there is a SP migration tool that allows you to migrate content that resides in SP online with classic sites to migrate that content to an SP online site with the modern experience?

Some background: last year our on-premise SP 2013 site was migrated to SP online using the same classic architecture, now we have been asked to move all of our content that resides in our current production environment to a new SP site that uses the modern experience.

Any guidance on this is most appreciated.

Comment: Is the new SP site with the modern experience on the same Office 365 tenant ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your current production environment is on SharePoint online and you want to migrate now from SharePoint online to SharePoint online with the modern experiences.

In this case, if you few sites or pages which runs on the classic experience, you convert those into modern experiences using the PnP script.

However, if you have more sites, then you can use the any third party migration tool like sharegate and there before migration in the tool you need to check the Chekbox of modern experiences for the list in the migration configuration section.